# How to use $inc operator for variables in MongoDB using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to build a "number of visitors" collection in mongoDb using Node.JS backend of my website. The frontend sends the following info to Node.JS backend as JSON.

1. isUniqueVisitor - 1 if yes, 0 if no
2. country         - standard country code  -  "JP", "IN", "UK", etc

My database looks like following

```
{
    "today": 2019-06-07,
    "uniqueVisitors": {
        "count": 230,
        "countries": {
            "JP": 102,
            "IN": 88,
            "UK": 30
        }
    }
}
```

It works well if I use $inc with fixed values

```
Eg. $inc: {count: 1}  // for string/integers keys
Eg. $inc: {"uniqueVisitors.count": 1} // inside quotes to access key of a JSON
```

**Main issue:**
*I am not able to access a document name using variable.*

```
Eg. $inc: {`uniqueVisitors.countries[${req.body.country}]`}
```

This creates an error as backticks can't be used for Mongo.
I tried with

```
Eg. $inc: {uniqueVisitors["countries"][req.body.country]}
```

But even this creates error.

I followed the web and found that mongo $set using variables can be realized by passing the required JSON directly to $set. Hence I resorted to code it the following way.

```
 mongoClient.connect(mongoURL, async function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Database connected");

            // Identifying my document with today's date
            var myQuery = {
                date: getTodayDate()
            };

            // Defining the JSON to be passed to uniqueVisitors $inc
            var uniqueVisitorsInc = {
                "uniqueVisitors": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "countries": {}
                }
            };

            // Populating the JSON to be passed to uniqueVisitors $inc => essentially asking to increase count by 1 and increase that country's count by 1

            uniqueVisitorsInc["uniqueVisitors"]["count"] = 1;
            uniqueVisitorsInc["uniqueVisitors"]["countries"][myData.country] = 1;

            var newValues = {
                $inc: uniqueVisitorsInc
            };
            await db.collection("visitorStats").update(myQuery, newValues, {upsert: true});
            db.close();
    });
```

> The above method worked well on editor but threw the following runtime error:

```
$inc requires numerical values
```

Basically asking me to pass values to $inc in {var1: 1, var2: 5} pattern.

Please help me bypass this weird situation.

I know I can do a two step process where I read the values first, increment in variable and $set it in Mongo.

But does anyone know how to overcome this situation using $inc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this update were hardcoded to update "JP" only, it'd need to look like:

```
$inc: { "uniqueVisitors.country.JP": 1 }
```

So you were almost there with the backtick method but change the syntax a bit and keep the `: 1` part like so:

```
$inc: { [`uniqueVisitors.country.${req.body.country}`]: 1 }
```

Comment: It still throws error with keeping keys in dot-notation instead of brackets.
It says "Property assignment expected." with a red line below my assignment
$inc: {`uniqueVisitors.count` : 1}

I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: After you edited your answer to include the JSON key access inside '[' and ']', it started to work well. Thank you so much.